# New 11.6" laptop with 16GB RAM

Tags: laptop, processor, memory

I have a [Lenovo ThinkPad 11e](https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-thinkpad-11e-11-6-celeron-n2940-4-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd-20d9s00c00/specs/) with an [Intel Celeron CPU N2940](https://ark.intel.com/products/82104/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N2940-2M-Cache-up-to-2-25-GHz-) and 8 GB of memory (Crucial Single DDR3 1600 MT/s).  Intel's website states the `Max Memory Size (dependent on memory type)` is 8 GB, but I would like to have 16+ GB?

Because of that, I am considering getting a new 11.6" laptop, such as the Yoga models which come with 16 GB, but the RAM is soldered (which is a deal breaker), its CPU is only a dual-core (unlike Celeron's quad-core), and it has only 1 USB slot.

In a perfect world, I would like a 11.6" laptop that has memory extendible to 32 GB and all the physical plugins that are on the 11e (i.e., HDMI connector, Ethernet Connector, Media card slot, and 2 USB 3.0 connectors). I've searched dozens of websites and it seems that Lenovo ThinkPad 11e is the most suitable, except for the max 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: It looks like you are asking two very different questions. The first one is off-topic here as it is a tech support question, but the second is suitable. What is your budget for the new laptop? Would it be acceptable if the laptop came with 32GB RAM that is soldered? How would you order your requirements (eg. What is most and least important to you)? What resolution are you looking for? Can you [edit] your question to include the answers to these questions please?

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the RAM limitation question. If you are still interested in the answer to that question, please visit [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your big problem is that you want it to have normal computer connections on the case, honestly.    "Slim and Light" is the main thing people look for when scoping out their laptop's casing, so even some ASUS Republic of Gamers laptops still only have two USB ports and very little else for connectivity.

I would recommend looking into a [Sager](https://www.sagernotebook.com/home.php). They specialize in customized gaming laptops, and most of the cases they use still appear to have the connections you requested.  Your size requirement is in your way on the RAM; 13" and smaller machines have a lot of tech packed in a small space, and actual physical size of the motherboard is influencing the number of RAM slots you have available or even necessitating permanent integration.  The problem isn't the CPU having a limitation, but the motherboard's physical capacity.